# Login error in php password compare to sql database

Tags: php, sql, authentication, compare

This code works beautifully to send the information put in the registry to the sql server, but is returning with "**Error logging in. The username or password does not match**" when I try to login using the data that was inputted during registration. I can see it in the database after it was created in registry to make sure I am typing everything correctly. I am almost certain the issue is around the **CheckLoginInDB** function, but it is rather difficult for me to find.

I want the code to compare the password correctly without returning the error and allowing a login.

```
    <?PHP
/*
    Registration/Login script from HTML Form Guide
    V1.0

    This program is free software published under the
    terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License.
    http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/lesser.html


This program is distributed in the hope that it will
be useful - WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the
implied warranty of MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

For updates, please visit:
http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-registration-form.html
http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-login-form.html

*/
require_once("class.phpmailer.php");
require_once("formvalidator.php");

class FGMembersite
{
    var $admin_email;
    var $from_address;

    var $username;
    var $pwd;
    var $database;
    var $tablename;
    var $connection;
    var $rand_key;

    var $error_message;

    //-----Initialization -------
    function FGMembersite()
    {
        $this->sitename = 'YourWebsiteName.com';
        $this->rand_key = '0iQx5oBk66oVZep';
    }

    function InitDB($host,$uname,$pwd,$database,$tablename)
    {
        $this->db_host  = $host;
        $this->username = $uname;
        $this->pwd  = $pwd;
        $this->database  = $database;
        $this->tablename = $tablename;

    }
    function SetAdminEmail($email)
    {
        $this->admin_email = $email;
    }

    function SetWebsiteName($sitename)
    {
        $this->sitename = $sitename;
    }

    function SetRandomKey($key)
    {
        $this->rand_key = $key;
    }

    //-------Main Operations ----------------------
    function RegisterUser()
    {
        if(!isset($_POST['submitted']))
        {
           return false;
        }

        $formvars = array();

        if(!$this->ValidateRegistrationSubmission())
        {
            return false;
        }

        $this->CollectRegistrationSubmission($formvars);

        if(!$this->SaveToDatabase($formvars))
        {
            return false;
        }

        if(!$this->SendUserConfirmationEmail($formvars))
        {
            return false;
        }

        $this->SendAdminIntimationEmail($formvars);

        return true;
    }

    function ConfirmUser()
    {
        if(empty($_GET['code'])||strlen($_GET['code'])<=10)
        {
            $this->HandleError("Please provide the confirm code");
            return false;
        }
        $user_rec = array();
        if(!$this->UpdateDBRecForConfirmation($user_rec))
        {
            return false;
        }

        $this->SendUserWelcomeEmail($user_rec);

        $this->SendAdminIntimationOnRegComplete($user_rec);

        return true;
    }    

    function Login()
    {
        if(empty($_POST['username']))
        {
            $this->HandleError("UserName is empty!");
            return false;
        }

        if(empty($_POST['password']))
        {
            $this->HandleError("Password is empty!");
            return false;
        }

        $username = trim($_POST['username']);
        $password = trim($_POST['password']);

        if(!isset($_SESSION)){ session_start(); }
        if(!$this->CheckLoginInDB($username,$password))
        {
            return false;
        }

        $_SESSION[$this->GetLoginSessionVar()] = $username;
        $_SESSION[$this->GetLoginSessionVar()] = $password;

        return true;
    }

    function CheckLogin()
    {
         if(!isset($_SESSION)){ session_start(); }

         $sessionvar = $this->GetLoginSessionVar();

         if(empty($_SESSION[$sessionvar]))
         {
            return false;
         }
         return true;
    }

    function UserFullName()
    {
        return isset($_SESSION['name_of_user'])?$_SESSION['name_of_user']:'';
    }

    function UserEmail()
    {
        return isset($_SESSION['email_of_user'])?$_SESSION['email_of_user']:'';
    }

    function LogOut()
    {
        session_start();

        $sessionvar = $this->GetLoginSessionVar();

        $_SESSION[$sessionvar]=NULL;

        unset($_SESSION[$sessionvar]);
    }

    function EmailResetPasswordLink()
    {
        if(empty($_POST['email']))
        {
            $this->HandleError("Email is empty!");
            return false;
        }
        $user_rec = array();
        if(false === $this->GetUserFromEmail($_POST['email'], $user_rec))
        {
            return false;
        }
        if(false === $this->SendResetPasswordLink($user_rec))
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    function ResetPassword()
    {
        if(empty($_GET['email']))
        {
            $this->HandleError("Email is empty!");
            return false;
        }
        if(empty($_GET['code']))
        {
            $this->HandleError("reset code is empty!");
            return false;
        }
        $email = trim($_GET['email']);
        $code = trim($_GET['code']);

        if($this->GetResetPasswordCode($email) != $code)
        {
            $this->HandleError("Bad reset code!");
            return false;
        }

        $user_rec = array();
        if(!$this->GetUserFromEmail($email,$user_rec))
        {
            return false;
        }

        $new_password = $this->ResetUserPasswordInDB($user_rec);
        if(false === $new_password || empty($new_password))
        {
            $this->HandleError("Error updating new password");
            return false;
        }

        if(false == $this->SendNewPassword($user_rec,$new_password))
        {
            $this->HandleError("Error sending new password");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    function ChangePassword()
    {
        if(!$this->CheckLogin())
        {
            $this->HandleError("Not logged in!");
            return false;
        }

        if(empty($_POST['oldpwd']))
        {
            $this->HandleError("Old password is empty!");
            return false;
        }
        if(empty($_POST['newpwd']))
        {
            $this->HandleError("New password is empty!");
            return false;
        }

        $user_rec = array();
        if(!$this->GetUserFromEmail($this->UserEmail(),$user_rec))
        {
            return false;
        }

        $pwd = trim($_POST['oldpwd']);

        if($user_rec['password'] != md5($pwd))
        {
            $this->HandleError("The old password does not match!");
            return false;
        }
        $newpwd = trim($_POST['newpwd']);

        if(!$this->ChangePasswordInDB($user_rec, $newpwd))
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    //-------Public Helper functions -------------
    function GetSelfScript()
    {
        return htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    }    

    function SafeDisplay($value_name)
    {
        if(empty($_POST[$value_name]))
        {
            return'';
        }
        return htmlentities($_POST[$value_name]);
    }

    function RedirectToURL($url)
    {
        header("Location: $url");
        exit;
    }

    function GetSpamTrapInputName()
    {
        return 'sp'.md5('KHGdnbvsgst'.$this->rand_key);
    }

    function GetErrorMessage()
    {
        if(empty($this->error_message))
        {
            return '';
        }
        $errormsg = nl2br(htmlentities($this->error_message));
        return $errormsg;
    }    
    //-------Private Helper functions-----------

    function HandleError($err)
    {
        $this->error_message .= $err."\r\n";
    }

    function HandleDBError($err)
    {
        $this->HandleError($err."\r\n mysqlerror:".mysql_error());
    }

    function GetFromAddress()
    {
        if(!empty($this->from_address))
        {
            return $this->from_address;
        }

        $host = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];

        $from ="nobody@$host";
        return $from;
    } 

    function GetLoginSessionVar()
    {
        $retvar = md5($this->rand_key);
        $retvar = 'usr_'.substr($retvar,0,10);
        return $retvar;
    }

    function CheckLoginInDB($username,$password)
    {
        if(!$this->DBLogin())
        {
            $this->HandleError("Database login failed!");
            return false;
        }          
        $username = $this->SanitizeForSQL($username);
        $pwdmd5 = md5($password);
        $qry = "Select name, email from $this->tablename where username='$username' and password='$pwdmd5' and confirmcode='y'";

        $result = mysql_query($qry,$this->connection);

        if(!$result || mysql_num_rows($result) <= 0)
        {
            $this->HandleError("Error logging in. The username or password does not match");
            return false;
        }

        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);


        $_SESSION['name_of_user']  = $row['name'];
        $_SESSION['email_of_user'] = $row['email'];

        return true;
    }

    function UpdateDBRecForConfirmation(&$user_rec)
    {
        if(!$this->DBLogin())
        {
            $this->HandleError("Database login failed!");
            return false;
        }   
        $confirmcode = $this->SanitizeForSQL($_GET['code']);

        $result = mysql_query("Select name, email from $this->tablename where confirmcode='$confirmcode'",$this->connection);   
        if(!$result || mysql_num_rows($result) <= 0)
        {
            $this->HandleError("Wrong confirm code.");
            return false;
        }
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
        $user_rec['name'] = $row['name'];
        $user_rec['email']= $row['email'];

        $qry = "Update $this->tablename Set confirmcode='y' Where  confirmcode='$confirmcode'";

        if(!mysql_query( $qry ,$this->connection))
        {
            $this->HandleDBError("Error inserting data to the table\nquery:$qry");
            return false;
        }      
        return true;
    }

    function ResetUserPasswordInDB($user_rec)
    {
        $new_password = substr(md5(uniqid()),0,10);

        if(false == $this->ChangePasswordInDB($user_rec,$new_password))
        {
            return false;
        }
        return $new_password;
    }

    function ChangePasswordInDB($user_rec, $newpwd)
    {
        $newpwd = $this->SanitizeForSQL($newpwd);

        $qry = "Update $this->tablename Set password='".md5($newpwd)."' Where  id_user=".$user_rec['id_user']."";

        if(!mysql_query( $qry ,$this->connection))
        {
            $this->HandleDBError("Error updating the password \nquery:$qry");
            return false;
        }     
        return true;
    }

    function GetUserFromEmail($email,&$user_rec)
    {
        if(!$this->DBLogin())
        {
            $this->HandleError("Database login failed!");
            return false;
        }   
        $email = $this->SanitizeForSQL($email);

        $result = mysql_query("Select * from $this->tablename where email='$email'",$this->connection);  

        if(!$result || mysql_num_rows($result) <= 0)
        {
            $this->HandleError("There is no user with email: $email");
            return false;
        }
        $user_rec = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);


        return true;
    }

    function SendUserWelcomeEmail(&$user_rec)
    {
        $mailer = new PHPMailer();

        $mailer->CharSet = 'utf-8';

        $mailer->AddAddress($user_rec['email'],$user_rec['name']);

        $mailer->Subject = "Welcome to ".$this->sitename;

        $mailer->From = $this->GetFromAddress();        

        $mailer->Body ="Hello ".$user_rec['name']."\r\n\r\n".
        "Welcome! Your registration  with ".$this->sitename." is completed.\r\n".
        "\r\n".
        "Regards,\r\n".
        "Webmaster\r\n".
        $this->sitename;

        if(!$mailer->Send())
        {
            $this->HandleError("Failed sending user welcome email.");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    function SendAdminIntimationOnRegComplete(&$user_rec)
    {
        if(empty($this->admin_email))
        {
            return false;
        }
        $mailer = new PHPMailer();

        $mailer->CharSet = 'utf-8';

        $mailer->AddAddress($this->admin_email);

        $mailer->Subject = "Registration Completed: ".$user_rec['name'];

        $mailer->From = $this->GetFromAddress();         

        $mailer->Body ="A new user registered at ".$this->sitename."\r\n".
        "Name: ".$user_rec['name']."\r\n".
        "Email address: ".$user_rec['email']."\r\n";

        if(!$mailer->Send())
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    function GetResetPasswordCode($email)
    {
       return substr(md5($email.$this->sitename.$this->rand_key),0,10);
    }

    function SendResetPasswordLink($user_rec)
    {
        $email = $user_rec['email'];

        $mailer = new PHPMailer();

        $mailer->CharSet = 'utf-8';

        $mailer->AddAddress($email,$user_rec['name']);

        $mailer->Subject = "Your reset password request at ".$this->sitename;

        $mailer->From = $this->GetFromAddress();

        $link = $this->GetAbsoluteURLFolder().
                '/resetpwd.php?email='.
                urlencode($email).'&code='.
                urlencode($this->GetResetPasswordCode($email));

        $mailer->Body ="Hello ".$user_rec['name']."\r\n\r\n".
        "There was a request to reset your password at ".$this->sitename."\r\n".
        "Please click the link below to complete the request: \r\n".$link."\r\n".
        "Regards,\r\n".
        "Webmaster\r\n".
        $this->sitename;

        if(!$mailer->Send())
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    function SendNewPassword($user_rec, $new_password)
    {
        $email = $user_rec['email'];

        $mailer = new PHPMailer();

        $mailer->CharSet = 'utf-8';

        $mailer->AddAddress($email,$user_rec['name']);

        $mailer->Subject = "Your new password for ".$this->sitename;

        $mailer->From = $this->GetFromAddress();

        $mailer->Body ="Hello ".$user_rec['name']."\r\n\r\n".
        "Your password is reset successfully. ".
        "Here is your updated login:\r\n".
        "username:".$user_rec['username']."\r\n".
        "password:$new_password\r\n".
        "\r\n".
        "Login here: ".$this->GetAbsoluteURLFolder()."/login.php\r\n".
        "\r\n".
        "Regards,\r\n".
        "Webmaster\r\n".
        $this->sitename;

        if(!$mailer->Send())
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }    

    function ValidateRegistrationSubmission()
    {
        //This is a hidden input field. Humans won't fill this field.
        if(!empty($_POST[$this->GetSpamTrapInputName()]) )
        {
            //The proper error is not given intentionally
            $this->HandleError("Automated submission prevention: case 2 failed");
            return false;
        }

        $validator = new FormValidator();
        $validator->addValidation("name","req","Please fill in Name");
        $validator->addValidation("email","email","The input for Email should be a valid email value");
        $validator->addValidation("email","req","Please fill in Email");
        $validator->addValidation("username","req","Please fill in UserName");
        $validator->addValidation("password","req","Please fill in Password");


        if(!$validator->ValidateForm())
        {
            $error='';
            $error_hash = $validator->GetErrors();
            foreach($error_hash as $inpname => $inp_err)
            {
                $error .= $inpname.':'.$inp_err."\n";
            }
            $this->HandleError($error);
            return false;
        }        
        return true;
    }

    function CollectRegistrationSubmission(&$formvars)
    {
        $formvars['name'] = $this->Sanitize($_POST['name']);
        $formvars['email'] = $this->Sanitize($_POST['email']);
        $formvars['username'] = $this->Sanitize($_POST['username']);
        $formvars['password'] = $this->Sanitize($_POST['password']);
    }

    function SendUserConfirmationEmail(&$formvars)
    {
        $mailer = new PHPMailer();

        $mailer->CharSet = 'utf-8';

        $mailer->AddAddress($formvars['email'],$formvars['name']);

        $mailer->Subject = "Your registration with ".$this->sitename;

        $mailer->From = $this->GetFromAddress();        

        $confirmcode = $formvars['confirmcode'];

        $confirm_url = $this->GetAbsoluteURLFolder().'/confirmreg.php?code='.$confirmcode;

        $mailer->Body ="Hello ".$formvars['name']."\r\n\r\n".
        "Thanks for your registration with ".$this->sitename."\r\n".
        "Please click the link below to confirm your registration.\r\n".
        "$confirm_url\r\n".
        "\r\n".
        "Regards,\r\n".
        "Webmaster\r\n".
        $this->sitename;

        if(!$mailer->Send())
        {
            $this->HandleError("Failed sending registration confirmation email.");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    function GetAbsoluteURLFolder()
    {
        $scriptFolder = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on')) ? 'https://' : 'http://';
        $scriptFolder .= $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . dirname($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
        return $scriptFolder;
    }

    function SendAdminIntimationEmail(&$formvars)
    {
        if(empty($this->admin_email))
        {
            return false;
        }
        $mailer = new PHPMailer();

        $mailer->CharSet = 'utf-8';

        $mailer->AddAddress($this->admin_email);

        $mailer->Subject = "New registration: ".$formvars['name'];

        $mailer->From = $this->GetFromAddress();         

        $mailer->Body ="A new user registered at ".$this->sitename."\r\n".
        "Name: ".$formvars['name']."\r\n".
        "Email address: ".$formvars['email']."\r\n".
        "UserName: ".$formvars['username'];

        if(!$mailer->Send())
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    function SaveToDatabase(&$formvars)
    {
        if(!$this->DBLogin())
        {
            $this->HandleError("Database login failed!");
            return false;
        }
        if(!$this->Ensuretable())
        {
            return false;
        }
        if(!$this->IsFieldUnique($formvars,'email'))
        {
            $this->HandleError("This email is already registered");
            return false;
        }

        if(!$this->IsFieldUnique($formvars,'username'))
        {
            $this->HandleError("This UserName is already used. Please try another username");
            return false;
        }        
        if(!$this->InsertIntoDB($formvars))
        {
            $this->HandleError("Inserting to Database failed!");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    function IsFieldUnique($formvars,$fieldname)
    {
        $field_val = $this->SanitizeForSQL($formvars[$fieldname]);
        $qry = "select username from $this->tablename where $fieldname='".$field_val."'";
        $result = mysql_query($qry,$this->connection);   
        if($result && mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    function DBLogin()
    {

        $this->connection = mysql_connect($this->db_host,$this->username,$this->pwd);

        if(!$this->connection)
        {   
            $this->HandleDBError("Database Login failed! Please make sure that the DB login credentials provided are correct");
            return false;
        }
        if(!mysql_select_db($this->database, $this->connection))
        {
            $this->HandleDBError('Failed to select database: '.$this->database.' Please make sure that the database name provided is correct');
            return false;
        }
        if(!mysql_query("SET NAMES 'UTF8'",$this->connection))
        {
            $this->HandleDBError('Error setting utf8 encoding');
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }    

    function Ensuretable()
    {
        $result = mysql_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM $this->tablename");   
        if(!$result || mysql_num_rows($result) <= 0)
        {
            return $this->CreateTable();
        }
        return true;
    }

    function CreateTable()
    {
        $qry = "Create Table $this->tablename (".
                "id_user INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,".
                "name VARCHAR( 128 ) NOT NULL ,".
                "email VARCHAR( 64 ) NOT NULL ,".
                "phone_number VARCHAR( 16 ) NOT NULL ,".
                "username VARCHAR( 16 ) NOT NULL ,".
                "password VARCHAR( 32 ) NOT NULL ,".
                "confirmcode VARCHAR(32) ,".
                "PRIMARY KEY ( id_user )".
                ")";

        if(!mysql_query($qry,$this->connection))
        {
            $this->HandleDBError("Error creating the table \nquery was\n $qry");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    function InsertIntoDB(&$formvars)
    {

        $confirmcode = $this->MakeConfirmationMd5($formvars['email']);

        $formvars['confirmcode'] = $confirmcode;

        $insert_query = 'insert into '.$this->tablename.'(
                name,
                email,
                username,
                password,
                confirmcode
                )
                values
                (
                "' . $this->SanitizeForSQL($formvars['name']) . '",
                "' . $this->SanitizeForSQL($formvars['email']) . '",
                "' . $this->SanitizeForSQL($formvars['username']) . '",
                "' . md5($formvars['password']) . '",
                "' . $confirmcode . '"
                )';      
        if(!mysql_query( $insert_query ,$this->connection))
        {
            $this->HandleDBError("Error inserting data to the table\nquery:$insert_query");
            return false;
        }        
        return true;
    }
    function MakeConfirmationMd5($email)
    {
        $randno1 = rand();
        $randno2 = rand();
        return md5($email.$this->rand_key.$randno1.''.$randno2);
    }
    function SanitizeForSQL($str)
    {
        if( function_exists( "mysql_real_escape_string" ) )
        {
              $ret_str = mysql_real_escape_string( $str );
        }
        else
        {
              $ret_str = addslashes( $str );
        }
        return $ret_str;
    }

 /*
    Sanitize() function removes any potential threat from the
    data submitted. Prevents email injections or any other hacker attempts.
    if $remove_nl is true, newline chracters are removed from the input.
    */
    function Sanitize($str,$remove_nl=true)
    {
        $str = $this->StripSlashes($str);

        if($remove_nl)
        {
            $injections = array('/(\n+)/i',
                '/(\r+)/i',
                '/(\t+)/i',
                '/(%0A+)/i',
                '/(%0D+)/i',
                '/(%08+)/i',
                '/(%09+)/i'
                );
            $str = preg_replace($injections,'',$str);
        }

        return $str;
    }    
    function StripSlashes($str)
    {
        if(get_magic_quotes_gpc())
        {
            $str = stripslashes($str);
        }
        return $str;
    }    
}
?>
```

Comment: Can you print out this - $qry = "Select name, email from $this->tablename where username='$username' and password='$pwdmd5' and confirmcode='y'";

Comment: What do you mean by 'print'? Are you asking to echo it?

Comment: I mean print the query using echo $qry; exit; ?

Comment: There is way too much code here. Isolate where the problem occurs and remove anything that is not relevant to the question.

Comment: First see if your "confirmcode" in the table is set to 'y'. Secondly append "mysql_error()" to the error message to see if there is actually any database error or if its simply not returning any rows.

Comment: When I change the confirmcode to y it will break the code and it no longer submits to the sql server and instead returns an error.          
Error inserting data to the table
query:insert into login_user(
name,
email,
username,
password,
confirmcode
)
values
(
"Bob Jones",
"bob@example.com",
"Drig",
"2264594786bf543bc0e78d848ae29391",
"22892684c7523dbb98ac9957503a1310"
)
mysqlerror:Unknown column 'confirmcode' in 'field list'
Inserting to Database failed!

Comment: Is there any column named confirmcode?